# How to get terraform data external to run a script both in plan and apply phases

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terraform

Trying to do something like this https://github.com/littlejo/terraform-ssm-tunnel. So terraform will create the tunnel both in running plan and apply.  The issue is that when running terraform plan -out tf.plan it works as expected but when running terraform apply tf.plan it does not create the tunnels. If you just do terraform apply it works fine also but when you run terraform apply with the plan output it does not.

I want terraform to run the scripts on both phases before trying to change use providers like postgresql and kubernetes_secret etc.  I have added stuff in the providers so it depends on the output of that module like in the examples with no luck.

One option would be something like this:

In a my_script directory create main.tf and my_script.sh

```
data "external" "my_script" {
  program = ["bash", "${path.module}/my_script.sh"]

  # Optional: Arguments to pass to the script
  query = {
    environment = var.environment
  }
}

output "result" {
  value = data.external.my_script.result.environment
}

resource "null_resource" "example" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "bash ${path.module}/my_script.sh ${data.external.my_script.result.environment}"
  }
}

variable "environment" {
  description = "Environment for the script"
  type        = string
}
```

And script

```
environment="$1"
echo "{\"environment\": \"$environment\"}"
my_variable=$((RANDOM))
mkdir /tmp/test_$my_variable
```

then in another directory do main.tf

```
module "my_script_module" {
  source      = "../my_script"
  environment = "production"
}
```

This seems to work but not great